# Compiler can't find libxml/parser.h

Tags: linux, include, debian, libxml2, suse

I am on Debian 8 (Jessie), 64 Bit. I installed `libxml2-dev`, which now sits in `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`.

But when I do (just like `libxml` docs say)

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
```

I only get when compiling (with `gcc`)

```
fatal error: libxml/parser.h: no such file or directory
```

Notes: On another machine, with an old 64 Bit Suse, where `libxml2-dev` sits in the exact same path and no other environment vars are set compared to the new Debian, it works perfectly fine. Problem occured while migrating from one to another computer using the exact same makefiles. **All** other `-dev` libs that I need just worked (with their documented `#include <path>`) after the migration (they were all installed with `apt-get`), only `libxml2-dev` is not found on compilation.

Do I need to do anything else to make `libxml2-dev` visible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to compile with explicite inclusion where the `parser.h` file is, i.e. smth like this

`g++ -I/usr/include/libxml2/`

---

Following environment variables can also be used for lookup of header files

```
CPATH
C_INCLUDE_PATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Find more information [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables)

Comment: Well, this works obviously. But what *could be* the reason that the lib is found on one system but not the other when sitting in the exact same place using the exact same makefile?

Comment: Aparently the `INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable is not updated to include also the `/usr/include/libxml2/`

Comment: just check it with `echo $INCLUDE_PATH`

Comment: This var does not exist at all, on both machines.

Comment: And `C_INCLUDE_PATH` ?

Comment: Or to shorten this: On both machines, there's no env var that has anything with `*INCL*` or a path with `*incl*` in it.

Comment: Run following command " \`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus\` -v " to see where gcc is looking for header files

Comment: On both theres `/usr/include` in the list (and some other ones in completly different places), but none with subfolder `libxml2`.

Comment: Thats the reason why it does not find the header by default, check the answer again I've updated it on how to modifty the default header files lookup behavior

Comment: But why does it work on the old Suse Linux where all this is missing as well?

Comment: The configurations on both system cannot be the same as its working on one host but not working on another host. The reasons can be many, e.g. wrongly configured and installed `libxml` on your new host. Or `OS` specific changes. Just try to check if the lib installed exactly to same directories on both systems.

Answer (score 19):

If you installed it: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxml2-doc` go into `/usr/include/libxml2` and copy or move all content from that folder on a level below: `cp -R libxml/ ../` After this for me it works.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this same problem on a Centos system.  I resolved it by doing the following:

```
yum install libxml2-devel
cd /usr/include
ln -s libxml2/libxml .
```

That was it. No change to environment variables or compiler switches.

Comment: This worked for me, but feels like a hack. I understand what's happening, but why is it needed?

Comment: Worked for me on Amazon Linux 2023

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pkg-config` to pass parameters to compiler. Like this

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0` example.c -o example.o
```

and to linker:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs libxml-2.0` example.o -o example
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04
Renamed **/usr/include/libxml2** to **/usr/include/libxml2_bak** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. The issue for me across multiple OS versions is that the package installed with apt-get puts the code into the folder

```
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/
```

You can't just move the libxml code up a directory and reference include the headers with libxml2/headerfile.h because some of the code files are pre-built to use the libxml include path.

I'm able to fix it without issue using a symlink.

```
cd /usr/include
sudo ln -s /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/ ./libxml
```

This will make it so that you can compile just using the simple

```
gcc main.c -lxml2
```