# Error installing Google PHP Interpreter

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to install the google PHP Interpreter on Ubuntu, following the installing docs for Google App Engine PHP.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php

When I try to build it:

```
$ ./configure
$ sudo make
```

I get this error:

```
fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
```

I have installed `libxml2-dev`, but does not help.

It's strange that there is no docs from Google covering this.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: You linked the docs page for installing the *SDK*, not for building the appengine-php interpreter from source. As far as why that's failing, is it possible that you need to restart the terminal for `libxml/parser.h` to show up?

Comment: Under PHP/Linux step 4. "Build and install the PHP interpreter". Should I skip that step?

Comment: Ah, that would be new to me. Okay, I'll assume that you didn't find any luck by attempting to restart the shell environment. In that case, can you run `locate parser.h | grep libxml2` to determine where it was installed on your system, and then you could check using `printenv` whether or not there were any env vars which could be used by the compiler which is failing to find the location of `libxml/parser.h`. It appears [others have had similar problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29847909/4270992) with `libxml/parser.h`'s location not being available to compilers.