# Ubuntu - Right protobuf paths for ./configure command

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I am following Google official documentation for GAE (Google app engine) installation.
Look at this part (relative to gae php extension): https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-extension

```
./configure --enable-gae --with-protobuf_inc=<include_path> --with-protobuf_lib=<lib_path>
```

The documentation says:

```
Set <include_path> and <lib_path> to where you have installed the protobuf headers and libraries in the previous step.
```

I always get an error in the terminal when I run the ./configure command, because I don't know which are the right protobuf paths.

P.s.
When installing Protobuf I followed this documentation:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md

My `/home/Experiments` folder contains 3 folders:
`php-src`, `appengine-php-extension`, `protobuf`.
The `protobuf` folder is where I have "git cloned" protobuf to install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions under **Building** in the linked repository for  the [App Engine PHP Runtime](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-extension), you'll find that in step 2, you choose an output directory when generating C++ source and header files for remote_api.proto and urlfetch_service.proto. That folder would be the correct one to supply via cmd args.

Comment: But that would be "." (dot) which means the same directory of the appengine-php-extension itself (that I have git cloned). I've already tried that but did not work (ex. "/home/mark/Experiments/appengine-php-extension"). I'll try again some variations but I doubt the result will change

Comment: I just noticed you never supplied which exact error you're getting. Could you edit the question to include that?